# Suggest me an IMU which is not affected by magnetic field

Tags: imu

I am using IMU for platform stabilization (Stewart Platform). But the issue is that there is a strong changing magnetic field. And I think that it might affect the accuracy of IMUs. Any suggestions?

Comment: `it might affect the accuracy` ... why don't you find out for certain?

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing / trying to do in more detail?  When I think of a Stewart Platform I think of something like a flight simulator where the base is stationary, and the platform is moving.  But you have the opposite?  I am also curious to know why a compass would be required over just an accelerometer and gyro.